# Como gerar XSD que obrigue envio do conteúdo de um elemento do XML utilizando JAX-WS

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jax-ws

Estou criando um web service com JAX-WS. Em uma operação, recebo um objeto que contém alguns atributos e eu quero que estes atributos sempre venham com valor.

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class RequestConsultarMargem {

    @XmlElement(name = "usuario-webservice", required = true, nillable = false)
    public String usuarioWebservice;

}
```

Na anotação `@XmlElement` especifiquei `required = true` para que valide se o elemento veio no XML, e `nillable = false`, para que valide se o conteúdo do elemento não está vazio.

Para que a validação seja executada, coloquei a anotação `@SchemaValidation` no serviço:

```
@WebService
@SchemaValidation
public class MargemWS {

    @WebMethod(operationName = "consultarMargem")
    @WebResult(name = "retorno-consulta-margem")
    public ResponseConsultarMargem consultarMargem(@WebParam(name = "consultar-margem")
                                                   @XmlElement(required = true, nillable = false) RequestConsultarMargem request) {
        ...
    }

}
```

Porém, ao subir o servidor e verificar o XSD gerado, o atributo `nillable` não foi colocado no atributo:

```
<xs:complexType name="requestConsultarMargem">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="usuario-webservice" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

O `nillable = false` funcionou, pois o elemento no XSD não veio com o atributo `minOccurs="0"`.

Estou utilizando JAX-WS na versão 2.2.10.

O que pode estar errado?